# Windows 10 fast startup locking non-OS physical HDD

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, multi-boot, win10-fast-startup

I've a system containing HDD and SSD, the SSD has one partition with Windows 10 installed on it, and the HDD has two partitions, the first is an Ubuntu partition and the second is a shared data partition.

I know that Windows fast startup will make the SSD read-only and that's fine, but why it is making the data partition on the HDD read-only also?

I've researched the issue, but all what I could find where people having the Windows and Linux partition on the same drive.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does Windows locking down the drive for Fast Startup work?](https://superuser.com/questions/1554458/how-does-windows-locking-down-the-drive-for-fast-startup-work)

Comment: not quiet, it doesn't take two different drives into consideration (most resources online about dual booting assume the user having two or different partitions on the same physical drive).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fast Startup affects all NTFS partitions Windows has mounted at the time it enters the semi-hibernated state characteristic of that feature, independent of their physical location.

That's why disabling Windows' Fast Startup is a MUST when dual-booting.

Answer (score 0):

It should *not* be locked except for writing, and [can be opened read-only](https://askubuntu.com/questions/296331/how-to-mount-a-hard-disk-as-read-only-from-the-terminal):

```
sudo mount --read-only <drive/path>
```

Preventing writing is done by marking the drive(s) as ["dirty"](https://superuser.com/questions/1554458/how-does-windows-locking-down-the-drive-for-fast-startup-work) to protect the OS system serialized to disk from being changed.